# Client connects to server randomly

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

I am trying to write a simple client/server program where the server first connects to the client, and sends the client a message. The client then echoes back the message to the server in uppercase.

The thing is, the connection is random; sometimes the client connects and sometimes it doesn't.

**EDIT:** when it doesn't connect, I get an "Address already in use" error. Is there some way to free the address on the server side?

**SERVER.C**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
  int welcomeSocket, newSocket, portNum, clientLen, nBytes;
  char buffer[1024];
  struct sockaddr_in serverAddr;
  struct sockaddr_storage serverStorage;
  socklen_t addr_size;
  int counter = 0;

  welcomeSocket = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

  portNum = 7891;

  serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  serverAddr.sin_port = htons(portNum);
  serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
  memset(serverAddr.sin_zero, '\0', sizeof serverAddr.sin_zero);  

  bind(welcomeSocket, (struct sockaddr *) &serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr));

  /*---- Listen on the socket, with 5 max connection requests queued ----*/
  if(listen(welcomeSocket,5)==0)
    printf("Listening\n");
  else
    printf("Error\n");

  /*---- Accept call creates a new socket for the incoming connection ----*/
  addr_size = sizeof serverStorage;
  while(1){
      newSocket = accept(welcomeSocket, (struct sockaddr *) &serverStorage, &addr_size);
/*    counter ++ ;*/
/*    printf("client connected: %d\n",counter);*/
      /*fork a child process to handle the new connection*/
      if(!fork()){
          /*---- Send message to the socket of the incoming connection ----*/
          strcpy(buffer,"Hello World\n");
          send(newSocket,buffer,13,0);
          recv(newSocket,buffer,13,0);

          /*---- Print the received message ----*/
          printf("Data received: %s",buffer);
          close(newSocket);
          exit(0);
      }
      /*if parent, close the socket and go back to listening new requests*/
      else{
          close(newSocket);
      }       
  }

  return 0;
}
```

**CLIENT.C**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(){
  int clientSocket, portNum, nBytes;
  char buffer[1024];
  struct sockaddr_in serverAddr;
  socklen_t addr_size;

  clientSocket = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

  portNum = 7891;

  serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  serverAddr.sin_port = htons(portNum);
  serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
  memset(serverAddr.sin_zero, '\0', sizeof serverAddr.sin_zero);  

  /*---- Connect the socket to the server using the address struct ----*/
  addr_size = sizeof serverAddr;
  connect(clientSocket, (struct sockaddr *) &serverAddr, addr_size);

  /*---- Read the message from the server into the buffer ----*/
  nBytes = recv(clientSocket, buffer, 1024, 0);

  /*---- Print the received message ----*/
  printf("Data received: %s",buffer);   

  for (int i=0;i<nBytes-1;i++){
     buffer[i] = toupper(buffer[i]);
  }

  send(clientSocket,buffer,nBytes,0);


  return 0;
}
```

Comment: "I cannot figure out why" - with one solitary exception, you don't check whether a single one of your system calls succeeds. Every system call which can fail gives you a way to check whether it did, and if it did, gives you a way to find out *why* it failed. If you deliberately neglect to make use of this information, you don't really have a moral right to expect your program to work, or to ask for help finding out why it doesn't. Check each of your system calls for success, and there's a high chance you'll answer your own question.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths can you give me some ideas as to how i can check why it failed?  I am new to socket programming

Comment: You seem to know what socket functions to call and how they work.  So you must have read the man pages.  And if you read the man pages, you should have also read the sections on what these functions return and how they indicate an error.

Comment: Calling `perror()` after it's failed is the easiest way. If you need more flexibility, you can work directly with `errno` and `strerror()`. For simple programs like this, you'll also generally want to terminate the program on failure, rather than just attempting to carry on regardless in a broken state.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths thanks for your help!

Comment: looking at posted client code.  needs `#include <unistd.h>` for the function `fork()` and function: `close()`.  there are three unused variables: `counter`, `nBytes` and `clientLen`  Also, `serverAddr.sin_port - htons( portNum);` is expecting `portNum` to be type: `uint16_t`  but it is declared as `int`,  Modifying byte order with different length values (usually) will not work as the posted code expects

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a single blank line  2) 2 space indent levels is not wide enough to be visible when using variable width fonts, suggest 4 spaces  per indent level. 3) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: error messages should be output to `stderr` not `stdout` and when the error indication is from a system function, should also output the reason the OS thinks the error occurred.  Therefore, rather than `printf()` suggest using `perror()`

Comment: regarding this code: `if(listen(welcomeSocket,5)==0)
    printf("Listening\n");
  else
    printf("Error\n");` when the error occurs should NOT continue executing the code, as if the operation were successful,  Suggest: `if(listen(welcomeSocket,5)==0)
    printf("Listening\n");
  else { perror( "listen failed" ); exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); }`

Comment: these two lines: `send(newSocket,buffer,13,0);
          recv(newSocket,buffer,13,0);`  use a 'magic' number 13. Strongly suggest letting the compiler handle the length calculation similar to :  `send(newSocket,buffer, strlen(buffer),0);
          recv(newSocket,buffer, strlen(buffer),0);`

Comment: when calling `send()` and when calling `recv()`,  always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.   Also, use the returned value from the `recv()` to place a NUL byte at the end of the data in the buffer[] before calling `printf("Data received: %s",buffer);`

Comment: the server code needs to check the returned value from the call to `bind()` and from the call to `socket()`  the posted code also has some other 'magic' numbers: 1024 and 7891.   'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis.  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, maintain.  Suggest using a `enum` statement or `#define` statements to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names, then use those meaningful names throughout the code.

Comment: when calling `connect()`, always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful. when initializing the `serverAddr` structure, the first statement should initialize the whole structure to '\0' then set the 3 fields of interest,  Then the code, amongst other things, does not need to address all the fields of the structure

Comment: this line: `nBytes = recv(clientSocket, buffer, 1024, 0);` would be much better written as: `nBytes = recv(clientSocket, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);`

Comment: the `recv()` function does not automatically NUL terminate the input data, so the returned value from the call to `recv() should be used to terminate the char array,  similar to: `buffer[ nBytes ] = '\0';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "address already in use" error occurrs on a call to `bind` when a socket is already bound to that port.  In the case of a listening TCP socket, that can happen when the program is restarted due to old connected sockets not being completely closed yet.

When binding a listening socket, you should set the `SO_REUSEADDR` socket option.  This will allow you to bind a TCP listening socket in these situations.

```
int option = 1;
if (setsockopt(welcomeSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &option, sizeof(option)) == -1) {
    perror("setsockopt for SO_REUSEADDR failed");
    exit(1);
}
```

This function should be called after `socket` but before `bind`.